# An equation over $\Bbb F_{3^k}$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Does the equation $$x^2=2=-1$$ have solutions in any extension field of $\Bbb F_3$?

Comment: Surely there must be a typo in the equation. Should the first equals sign be a minus or a plus?

Comment: @Calle: The second equality is just reminding us that $2=-1$ in $\mathbb F_3$.

Comment: Oh, of course! Silly me.

Comment: And it’s extremely easy to do computations in the field of nine elements. I recommend to you in the strongest terms the expenditure of a few minutes working things out in this field, using @HenningMakholm’s description. For instance: find an element generating the multiplicative group, and write out its successive powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $X^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$, as it has no root. (Check by direct computation.)

The splitting field of  $X^2 + 1$ is thus a degree $2$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$. It is thus, $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$.

It follows that $X^2 + 1$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{3^k}$ if and only if $k$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

*Every* field has an algebraic closure, and by definition the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_3$ will contain solutions to any polynomial equation (of positive degree) you throw at it.

In your particular case, however, we don't need to go that far. Since $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_3$, $\mathbb F_9$ can be constructed as $\mathbb F_3[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle$, and thus the image of $X$ in that quotient will satisfy $X^2=-1$.